# Analytic function with $f(1/n) \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $f$ is real valued for $-1<x<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

**Exercise** Let $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic where $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$. Show that if $f(\frac{1}{n})$ is real whenever $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$, then $f$ is real-valued whenever $-1 < z < 1$.

I think one way of showing this is to show that the coefficients of the power series of $f$ centered at $z=0$ are real.

Again, let $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $f(\frac{1}{n}) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n\geq 2$. Since $f$ is analytic, it has a Taylor series representation which we center at $z=0$,

$$f(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(z-0)^k$$

Now let $n \geq 2$,

$$f\Big( \frac{1}{n} \Big) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^k$$

Then this series is real valued. I am failing to see, however, how this fact helps me. Does anyone have any advice on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I have fixed it. But still remain in mystery about the problem.